# No signal over DVI to HDMI cable

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I tried to connect my backup gaming rig to my mounted tv.

My backup rig has a Ati Radeon HD 4670, which has a VGA, HDMI and DVI-I connectors for output.

I tried using a DVI-D to HDMI cable, in order to connect my desktop over to my tv by HDMI, so, it goes like this

```
PC DVI-I output -> DVI-D end -> HDMI end -> TV HDMI input
```

But, tv reports no signal and pc claims to see something connected but not recognized.

I had tested the cable and it's working, as in my work I have a secondary monitor with a DVI-D output (for those curious ones, it's an DELL P190S), and used to connect it to my laptop over it's HDMI input. Though I saw no advantage over using the simple vga connector, but I know it's working

Comment: Connect an additional monitor to your PC and verify it detects the TV.

Comment: Why are you using a DVI-D to HDMI cable instead of simply using an HDMI cable to connect your PC to your TV?  Your TV has stricter requirements for HDMI then your monitor does.

Comment: @Ramhound because It's what I had at hand at the moment I was setting it up all. I'm aware I can use a hdmi cable, but at the moment I don't have one and I want to use this one. Hence, this is also educational for me

Comment: @DanielB I do have a 15" monitor through vga. When I press the detect button, it states it finds something connected but not recognized. TV show "no signal" on that input